# How to display local images from a remotely loaded URL web page?

Tags: android

I have implemented a mobile web page with some pictures that are referencing to some pictures in android assets.

`<img src="file:///android_asset/assets/pictures/1.jpg" border="0" />`

(1.jpg is under android directory /assets/pictures/)

This page is put in my server.

In the activity this web page is loaded into the webview. But why the webview can't display that picture?

```
webview.loadUrl("http://abc.com/page.html");
```

=======edit========

here are the settings

```
    final MyActivity activity = this;
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
        }
    });
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
            String description, String failingUrl) {

        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
    webview.loadUrl("http://abc.com/page.html");
```

Android SDK:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Comment: shouldn't be a problem with the image tag you mentioned, can you also specify the android version and possibly the webchromeclient settings that you are doing in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pages loaded by loadUrl() method do not load images linked with file:///android_asset/... but you can fetch the HTML page using org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.HttpGet() and then pass it to the WebView with loadDataWithBaseURL() - that way WebView will load resources linked with file:///android_asset/...

Answer (score 0):

You could use base64 embedded images in your page content (no need to struggle with links to restricted filesystem)

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,xxxxxxxxx"/>
```